# How to make an Objective-C Swift Package a clang module, so that`#import "FrameworkName/Header.h"` works

Tags: swift, objective-c, clang

In [Behind the scenes with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/415/), Jürgen Ributzka said **"always specify framework name when you import your public or private headers"**: i.e. use `#import <PetKit/Petkit.h>`, not `#import "Petkit.h"`.

However, in my Swift Package, imports with the framework name (e.g. `Petkit/`) does not work, I get a `file not found` error during compilation. Removing the framework name from imports fixed it, and the project builds successfully.

Is there a way to make an Objective-C Swift Package automatically generate a Clang module/ clang virtual file system (virtual abstraction of a framework). I assume this is the problem. Essentially I want to fix the compiler issue without removing the framework name from the imports.

From 29:55 in [Behind the scenes with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/415/)

[image]

---

Someone else has faced this issue before [here](https://joesusnick.medium.com/swift-package-manager-with-a-mixed-swift-and-objective-c-project-part-2-2-e71dad234e6):

> When you go to build your Swift package you’ll get the error:
> 'MyModule/SomeHeader.h' file not found

He solved it using macros. This is a very tedious way of doing imports in a large project.

```
#if SOME_BUILD_SYSTEM
#import <MyModule/SomeHeader.h>
#else 
#import "SomeHeader.h"
#endif
```